# Auto mount hard disk

Tags: mount, startup

I got a dual-boot Windows and an Apricity OS (based on ArchLinux) machine.

Windows is installed on `/dev/sda4`. Apricity OS is installed on `/dev/sdb`.

What I want to achieve is not to have to type password every time I want to get into files from Windows partition.

Comment: Consider using the automounter (`autofs`) with an entry for `sda4` in `/etc/auto.misc`. This would keep the filesystem unmounted except when it was in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have your mounting directory ready, say /mnt/windows, and in your /etc/fstab add a line for it like :

```
/dev/sda4       /mnt/windows        ntfs        noauto,x-systemd.automount,user,rw,umask=111,dmask=000    0  0
```

And it should now be mounted at boot time and could be accessed without the need for a password everytime (since it is already mounted)